# How to save a number as a String in Excel?

Tags: excel, numbers

How to save a number as a String in Excel?

When I try to enter a number, 00112233, Excel automatically formats it as 112233 and saving it as number. But I want the preceeding 0's not to be truncated and save the number as string.

As a workaround I'm using quotes ("") to save the actual string.

Any suggestion...??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you put a single quote in front of the number, it will be stored as text.

Answer (score 5):

If you pre-format the input cells with `TEXT` format you can just enter `00112233` or whatever and it will display as entered and be stored as text. To do that select a cell or range of cells and right click - in dialog box choose `"Format Cells"` and then in the next box choose `Number` > `Text`

Note you can't change to TEXT format **after** input, or rather you can change the format but it has no effect!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use single quotes to keep it as text:

```
'00112233
```

Will store `00112233` in the cell.

Otherwise, if you have many cells already in number format, and you need them to be in text format with 8 digits (including zeros), you can use the formula on the data:

```
=text(A1,"00000000")
```

(there are 8 zeros there)

Then, copy the column containing the formula, paste in place as values (Paste Special > Values) and delete the previous column.