# Trimming a string as it is retrieved in a for loop?

Tags: vba, excel

I have this for loop which retrieves the phone number from Google maps pages of a business.

```
               For Each a In Array("_Xbe _ZWk kno-fv")
                aa = ""
                aa = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName(a)(0).innerText
                If Len(bb) > 0 Then
                Wksht.Cells(LngRow, 10) = aa
                Exit For
              End If

           Next
```

It works great BUT the phone number comes in the format of (xx) xxxx xxxx. I want it to be xxxxxxxxxx. How do you trim and concate in the middle of a for loop?

Comment: You could potentially just use `Wksht.Cells(LngRow, 10) = Replace(Replace(Replace(aa,")",""),"(","")," ","")`.  (I am also assuming that the `, 10` is referring to column J, not to the 10 character long string you are after.)

Comment: That actually works pretty well except its cutting of the first number of the 10 digit phone number

Comment: It is completely irrelevant that the code is executed within a loop. You might want to change the title.

Comment: use trim before replace function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to change the NumberFormat of the Column and use replace to get rid of the parenthesis ans spaces.

```
Wksht.Columns(10).NumberFormat = "0000000000"

For Each a In Array("_Xbe _ZWk kno-fv")
    aa = ""
    aa = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName(a)(0).innerText
    aa = Replace(aa, "(", "")
    aa = Replace(aa, ")", "")
    aa = Replace(aa, " ", "")

    If Len(bb) > 0 Then
        Wksht.Cells(LngRow, 10) = aa
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Same weird problem it cuts off the first number but does everything else fine.

Comment: This code will not remove anything other then parenthesis and spaces.  `Debug.Print aa` before it is modified and see what you get.  Can I get a sample of the actual tag html?

Comment: Could the fact the first number is always 0 be a problem?

Comment: @TummyTum - It isn't "cutting off" the first number - Excel isn't [storing it as text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123036/how-to-save-a-number-as-a-string-in-excel).

Comment: Thanks Excel, is there anyway around that besides putting a commo or something before it?

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
 For Each a In Array("_Xbe _ZWk kno-fv")
            aa = ""
            aa = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName(a)(0).innerText
            If Len(aa) > 0 Then
            aa =trim(aa)
            aa = mid(aa, 2,2) & mid(aa,6,4)& right(aa,len(aa)-10)

            Wksht.Cells(LngRow, 10) = aa
            Exit For
          End If

       Next
```

Comment: Didn't work, but I also just realized I wrote If Len(bb), i don't know why I did that it should be aa but neither make a difference :S

Comment: No it just runs the code as normal with the original number format.

Comment: It worked better, got rid of the brackets but the spaces are still there.

Comment: Still cuts off the first number for some reason, example number is (02) 1234 5678

Answer (score 0):

The obligatory regular expression answer...

```
For Each a In Array("_Xbe _ZWk kno-fv")
    aa = vbNullString
    aa = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName(a)(0).innerText
    If Len(bb) > 0 Then
        With New RegExp
            .Pattern = "[^\d]"
            .Global = True
            Wksht.Cells(LngRow, 10) = .Replace(aa, vbNullString)
        End With
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Note: This requires a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions, or you can use late binding by using `With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")` instead of `With New RegExp`.